# SSL certificate issue with git operation on pfsense

Tags: linux, ssl, linux-networking, git, pfsense

I have installed `pfsense` latest version and user are working on Phpstorm and Netbeans editors with `git (https)`.

On gateway, I have installed pfsense server and configure `transparent proxy` using squid+squidguard`.

then Pfsense self sign certificate installed all machine and browsing is working fine but Issue is that,  when user perform `fetch/push` operation etc on editor using `git` then getting some `certificate related errors`.

On server site, We can't change it (disable the https or no verification etc).

Please let me know how to resolve this error on client machine or pfsense firewall.

Comment: You'll want to at least give what error you're receiving...

Comment: I get "repository test has failed" error when make a clone in phpstorm, if i disable the https in pfsense or sslVerify = false  then i am able to create clone. Also add ssl certificate in c:\User\Admin\..gitconfig : "sslCAInfo = /cert/mycert.cer"
in windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

The client has to ignore the self-signed cert, not the server. This question seems to have what you are looking for: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537763/git-ssl-without-env-git-ssl-no-verify-true`

Comment: I don't want to disable ssl certificate.